# How to handle back pressed on sub activity of TabActivity?

Tags: android, tabs, tabactivity

I am implementing Tab environment as follow :

There is one class `TabScreenABCActivity extends TabActivity`,in that i have handled the tabchange functionality.

I have implemented `MyTabGroupActivity extends TabGroupActivity`. From this class, i have called MyActivity like so:

```
startChildActivity(getResources().getString(R.string.MyActivity), new Intent(this,MyActivity.class));
```

Now, `MyActivity extends TabGroupActivity`, from this class i called two other classes using intent like so:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setClass(MyActivity.this,XYZActivity.class);
TabGroupActivity tab = (TabGroupActivity) MyActivity.this.getParent();
tab.startChildActivity("Tab", intent);
```

I have also overridden method to go back Activity `onBackPressed()` method in each activity. But it is not working properly. Can anyone guide me on how to handle it?

Comment: You'll find some idea when you have a look at [here](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

Comment: `onBackPressed()` works for me. Please provide some code.

Comment: plz check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675194/android-tabactivity-back-button-functionality-with-multiple-child-activities

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below link for perfect TabGroupActivity 
[Handling multiple activies under single tab](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is code for hard back Button of your device. here put your intent.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

             Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
                 startActivity(i);  

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```